# Open window such that is shows on all desktops

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a screenshot thing, what it does is it takes a screenshot of the current visible stuff, then opens a full screen window covering everything. However this opens on the desktop of the parent window which is on desktop 1. And if a user had desktop 2 focused (due to like fullscreen app or something) then the window that opened will not show on desktop 2.

So I was wondering if there is a window level or something (I tried all the window levels) that will make it such that a window appears on all desktops.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like either `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces` or `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary`. Set it as the `collectionBehavior` of the window.

(You probably want to set the window level, too, but that's about ordering rather than collection/Spaces behavior. And if you have a Window menu, then you probably also want `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle`.)

Comment: Thanks very much @Peter, my problem is i have to do this on already opened windows. So I'm having a hard time setting it :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866399/setcollectionbehavior-not-taking-affect-on-already-opened-window?s=2|0.0000 do you have any advice on that?

Comment: Sorry for the bump @Peter but I havent been able to pull this off yet :( Is it possible to pull this off from ctypes on run time? I do stuff in js-ctypes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

Comment: @Noitidart: I've never used js-ctypes, but there's a strong chance that this may actually be an AppKit limitation. I suggest creating an Objective-C sample app to try it out without going through js-ctypes; if it works there, it's a js-ctypes issue, and if it doesn't, you should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Ah thanks @Peter, I don't have objc experience, just porting to jsctypes haha. I'll ask around see if someone can test this for me. I basically need to ask someone to see if they can convert an existing window to apprea on all spaces. If you have a chance may you try that? :P Ill start asking around too just thought I would start with you :P thanks Peter!

Comment: Works!  Just did `[nswindow collectionBheavior]` to get the current behavior then I modify it and then set it back with `[nswindow setCollectionBehavior: newbehavior`! However the window is not showing over other PIDs may you please take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442644/nswindowcollectionbehaviorcanjoinallspaces-window-not-showing-if-other-process-i