# setCollectionBehavior not taking affect on already opened window

Tags: objective-c, macos

A user clicks a "take screenshot in 10seconds" button in my application. Then user focuses another app and makes it full screen. While user is focused in this full screen app, my 10sec timer now hits 0. My application opens a window that is full size of monitor, it draws the screenshot on it. But now I want the window to show on all spaces. I tried this:

```
[window setCollectionBehavior:(16 | 1 | 256)];
```

But it is not making the window show over the users current space (Which is the full screen app) do you guys know whats up?

Just to verify, the magic numbers for these constants are:

```
var NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary = 1 << 4; // 16
var NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces = 1 << 0; // 1
var NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary = 1 << 8; // 256
var NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace = 1 << 1;// 2
```

Is this correct? I am doing this via ctypes so have to use magic numbers.

I also tried:

```
 [window setCanBeVisibleOnAllSpaces:YES]
```

But it didnt work.

Thanks

Edit:
So this window is already opened and I dont have access to the storyboard etc as mentioned in a2's answer below, we discussed it in chat and we need to hook into it somehow to make this take affect, is there anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code either in your xib / storyboard, either in your `NSWindowController` subclass `-windowDidLoad` method, either in your designated initialiser of your `NSWindow` subclass :

```
- (void) awakeFromNib { 
    [self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces]; 
}
```

OR

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)styleMask
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {
    if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:styleMask  backing:bufferingType defer:flag]) {
        [self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
    }
    return self;
}
```

OR if you have a `NSWindowController`

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [[self window] setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
}
```

OR Edit the nib file and add this behaviour to your window in XCode.

Comment: Ah drats, what if the window is a pre-existing window already open, its not possible? I am doing this via ctypes :(

Comment: No, you can't do that on an existing window, if you don't own it. Could you elaborate your approach ? Not familiar with ctypes

Comment: Ah thanks by chance do you use firefox? Can you chat with stackoverflow chat? :)

Comment: I created chat room for us: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26677/chat-for-topic-http-stackoverflow-com-q-31866399-1828637 please :)

Comment: Hi a2 I took a nap and had an idea in my dream :P (actually it was something i was thinking about the other day) What if I moved the window to the other workspace would that work?

Comment: you can try, first try then think, gets stuff done much faster

Comment: Thanks so much a24! I actually do this in js-ctypes so its lots of work so didnt start on this. But you checking up makes me want to check up on this workspace moving thing.  But can you help me test something, in my tests it seems when you make an app full screen, and it slides over, that workspace doesnt get a new workspace number. Is that true?

Comment: Hi @Stefan I tested again, the "full screen" space really isn't a workspace, using the CG private methods - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3664c5c2059c9aa6779f - the workspace number would remain same while on fullscreen window. So moving to different workspaces doesnt work :(

Comment: Ping me in the weekend, i'll come back to try out some stuff. Btw, it's been a year :-)

Comment: Thanks brother! I'll ping ya. Yeah haha unsolved things bother me forever :P I always try to get it done :P