# Set focus of NSWindow on top, even if changing of virtual desk

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindow

I'm doing an application which consists of asking a question after a certain time, and the user can't do anything more, unless he answers the question, I've managed to mantain the window always on top by setting a 9999 level:

```
[_idleWindow setLevel:9999];
```

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid changing virtual desktop when the window is open, or to focus the window again when you change the virtual desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few researches on Google, I have found the solution on another [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866399/setcollectionbehavior-not-taking-affect-on-already-opened-window).

Solution:

```
You need to add this code either in your xib / storyboard, either in your NSWindowController subclass -windowDidLoad method, either in your designated initialiser of your NSWindow subclass :

- (void) awakeFromNib { 
    [self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces]; //this was the one that worked for me
}
OR

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)styleMask
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {
    if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:styleMask  backing:bufferingType defer:flag]) {
        [self setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
    }
    return self;
}
OR if you have a NSWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [[self window] setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];
}
OR Edit the nib file and add this behaviour to your window in XCode.
```

Credits: [Stefan Szekeres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889814/stefan-szekeres)

Answer (score 2):

Look at setCollectionBehavior:

```
[_idleWindow setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenDisallowsTiling|NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
```

might do the trick.

Also, if you can use  NSPanel instead of NSWindow, you can add the style mask: `NSWindowStyleMaskNonactivatingPanel`  to give your window key status even when your app isn't active. (you'll need to implement `canBecomeKeyWindow` in the NSPanel subclass)

Comment: I just had the time to test your solution and it doesn't work, will test the NSPanel